# My app is failing to run carousel package in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, carousel, pubspec

I have added "carousel_pro: ^1.0.0" under dependencies in my pubspec.yaml file and imported in my desired file using "import 'package:carousel_pro/carousel_pro.dart';".

Heres the whole file

```js
 import 'package:carousel_pro/carousel_pro.dart';
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    class CarouselImages extends StatefulWidget {

      final List<String> imagesListUrl;

      CarouselImages(this.imagesListUrl);

      @override
      _CarouselImagesState createState() => _CarouselImagesState();
    }

    class _CarouselImagesState extends State<CarouselImages> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {

        Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

        return Container(
          height: size.height * 0.35,
          child: Carousel(
            dotSize: 5,
            dotBgColor: Colors.transparent,
            autoplay: false,
            images: [
              AssetImage(widget.imagesListUrl[0],),
              AssetImage(widget.imagesListUrl[1],),
              AssetImage(widget.imagesListUrl[2],),
              AssetImage(widget.imagesListUrl[3],),
              AssetImage(widget.imagesListUrl[4],),
              AssetImage(widget.imagesListUrl[5],),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

But the code is not running, I have a red line underlined at the import and carousel widget.
Hovering over the import code it says:Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:carousel_pro/carousel_pro.dart'.dart(uri_does_not_exist)

and when I hover over the widget it says The method 'Carousel' isn't defined for the type `_CarouselImagesState'.dart(undefined_method)`
Quick fixes are telling me to create class, method or function.

Help me solve this

I tried upgrading and downgrading flutter and dart versions, and also the carousel package. I also tried changing from carousel_pro to carousel_slider but its still not working.

I expected that this would solve the issue by having a more stable version of dart and flutter or the dependency

Answer (score 0):

1.this library is not supported by latest versions of flutter

2.in the description of the question you did not indicate the version of flutter installed on your PC

3.I recommend trying another library, for example this [one](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_carousel_widget)

[screenshot from pub dev](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kdko4.png)

Answer (score 0):

The carousel package is on some old version of Flutter.
Let me help. Create your own carousel file. Here's the code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

enum DotPosition {
  topLeft,
  topCenter,
  topRight,
  bottomLeft,
  bottomCenter,
  bottomRight
}

class Carousel extends StatefulWidget {
  //All the images on this Carousel.
  final List? images;

  //All the images on this Carousel.
  final dynamic defaultImage;

  //The transition animation timing curve. Default is [Curves.ease]
  final Curve animationCurve;

  //The transition animation duration. Default is 300ms.
  final Duration animationDuration;

  // The base size of the dots. Default is 8.0
  final double dotSize;

  // The increase in the size of the selected dot. Default is 2.0
  final double dotIncreaseSize;

  // The distance between the center of each dot. Default is 25.0
  final double dotSpacing;

  // The Color of each dot. Default is Colors.white
  final Color dotColor;

  // The background Color of the dots. Default is [Colors.grey[800].withOpacity(0.5)]
  final Color? dotBgColor;

  // The Color of each increased dot. Default is Colors.white
  final Color dotIncreasedColor;

  // Enable or Disable the indicator (dots). Default is true
  final bool showIndicator;

  //Padding Size of the background Indicator. Default is 20.0
  final double indicatorBgPadding;

  //How to show the images in the box. Default is cover
  final BoxFit boxFit;

  //Enable/Disable radius Border for the images. Default is false
  final bool borderRadius;

  //Border Radius of the images. Default is [Radius.circular(8.0)]
  final Radius? radius;

  //Indicator position. Default bottomCenter
  final DotPosition dotPosition;

  //Move the Indicator Horizontally relative to the dot position
  final double dotHorizontalPadding;

  //Move the Indicator Vertically relative to the dot position
  final double dotVerticalPadding;

  //Move the Indicator From the Bottom
  final double moveIndicatorFromBottom;

  //Remove the radius bottom from the indicator background. Default false
  final bool noRadiusForIndicator;

  //Enable/Disable Image Overlay Shadow. Default false
  final bool overlayShadow;

  //Choose the color of the overlay Shadow color. Default Colors.grey[800]
  final Color? overlayShadowColors;

  //Choose the size of the Overlay Shadow, from 0.0 to 1.0. Default 0.5
  final double overlayShadowSize;

  //Enable/Disable the auto play of the slider. Default true
  final bool autoplay;

  //Duration of the Auto play slider by seconds. Default 3 seconds
  final Duration autoplayDuration;

  //On image tap event, passes current image index as an argument
  final void Function(int)? onImageTap;

  //On image change event, passes previous image index and current image index as arguments
  final void Function(int, int)? onImageChange;

  const Carousel({
    Key? key,
    this.images,
    this.animationCurve = Curves.ease,
    this.animationDuration = const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
    this.dotSize = 8.0,
    this.dotSpacing = 25.0,
    this.dotIncreaseSize = 2.0,
    this.dotColor = Colors.white,
    this.dotBgColor,
    this.dotIncreasedColor = Colors.white,
    this.showIndicator = true,
    this.indicatorBgPadding = 10.0,
    this.boxFit = BoxFit.cover,
    this.borderRadius = false,
    this.radius,
    this.dotPosition = DotPosition.bottomCenter,
    this.dotHorizontalPadding = 0.0,
    this.dotVerticalPadding = 0.0,
    this.moveIndicatorFromBottom = 0.0,
    this.noRadiusForIndicator = false,
    this.overlayShadow = false,
    this.overlayShadowColors,
    this.overlayShadowSize = 0.5,
    this.autoplay = true,
    this.autoplayDuration = const Duration(seconds: 3),
    this.onImageTap,
    this.onImageChange,
    this.defaultImage,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State createState() => CarouselState();
}

class CarouselState extends State<Carousel> {
  Timer? timer;
  int _currentImageIndex = 0;
  PageController? _controller = PageController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    if (widget.images != null && widget.images!.isNotEmpty) {
      if (widget.autoplay) {
        timer = Timer.periodic(widget.autoplayDuration, (_) {
          if (_controller!.hasClients) {
            if (_controller!.page!.round() == widget.images!.length - 1) {
              _controller!.animateToPage(
                0,
                duration: widget.animationDuration,
                curve: widget.animationCurve,
              );
            } else {
              _controller!.nextPage(
                  duration: widget.animationDuration,
                  curve: widget.animationCurve);
            }
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller!.dispose();
    _controller = null;
    timer?.cancel();
    timer = null;
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<Widget> listImages = (widget.images != null &&
            widget.images!.isNotEmpty)
        ? widget.images!.map<Widget>(
            (netImage) {
              if (netImage is ImageProvider) {
                return Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: widget.borderRadius
                        ? BorderRadius.all(
                            widget.radius ?? standardBorderRadius as Radius,
                          )
                        : null,
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      //colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2), BlendMode.dstATop),
                      image: netImage,
                      fit: widget.boxFit,
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: widget.overlayShadow
                      ? Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            gradient: LinearGradient(
                              begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                              end: Alignment.center,
                              stops: [0.0, widget.overlayShadowSize],
                              colors: [
                                widget.overlayShadowColors != null
                                    ? widget.overlayShadowColors!
                                        .withOpacity(1.0)
                                    : Colors.grey[800]!.withOpacity(1.0),
                                widget.overlayShadowColors != null
                                    ? widget.overlayShadowColors!
                                        .withOpacity(0.0)
                                    : Colors.grey[800]!.withOpacity(0.0)
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      : Container(),
                );
              } else if (netImage is FadeInImage) {
                return ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: widget.borderRadius
                      ? BorderRadius.all(
                          widget.radius ??
                              const Radius.circular(
                                borderDouble,
                              ),
                        )
                      : standardBorderRadius,
                  child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        gradient: LinearGradient(
                          begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                          end: Alignment.center,
                          stops: [0.0, widget.overlayShadowSize],
                          colors: [
                            widget.overlayShadowColors != null
                                ? widget.overlayShadowColors!.withOpacity(1.0)
                                : Colors.grey[800]!.withOpacity(1.0),
                            widget.overlayShadowColors != null
                                ? widget.overlayShadowColors!.withOpacity(0.0)
                                : Colors.grey[800]!.withOpacity(0.0)
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: netImage),
                );
              } else {
                return netImage;
              }
            },
          ).toList()
        : [
            widget.defaultImage is ImageProvider
                ? Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: widget.borderRadius
                          ? BorderRadius.all(
                              widget.radius ?? const Radius.circular(8.0))
                          : null,
                      image: DecorationImage(
                        //colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2), BlendMode.dstATop),
                        image: widget.defaultImage,
                        fit: widget.boxFit,
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: widget.overlayShadow
                        ? Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              gradient: LinearGradient(
                                begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                end: Alignment.center,
                                stops: [0.0, widget.overlayShadowSize],
                                colors: [
                                  widget.overlayShadowColors != null
                                      ? widget.overlayShadowColors!
                                          .withOpacity(1.0)
                                      : Colors.grey[800]!.withOpacity(1.0),
                                  widget.overlayShadowColors != null
                                      ? widget.overlayShadowColors!
                                          .withOpacity(0.0)
                                      : Colors.grey[800]!.withOpacity(0.0)
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                        : Container(),
                  )
                : widget.defaultImage,
          ];

    final bottom = [
      DotPosition.bottomLeft,
      DotPosition.bottomCenter,
      DotPosition.bottomRight
    ].contains(widget.dotPosition)
        ? widget.dotVerticalPadding
        : null;
    final top = [
      DotPosition.topLeft,
      DotPosition.topCenter,
      DotPosition.topRight
    ].contains(widget.dotPosition)
        ? widget.dotVerticalPadding
        : null;
    double? left = [DotPosition.topLeft, DotPosition.bottomLeft]
            .contains(widget.dotPosition)
        ? widget.dotHorizontalPadding
        : null;
    double? right = [DotPosition.topRight, DotPosition.bottomRight]
            .contains(widget.dotPosition)
        ? widget.dotHorizontalPadding
        : null;

    if (left == null && right == null) {
      left = right = 0.0;
    }

    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Builder(
          builder: (_) {
            Widget pageView = PageView(
              physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              controller: _controller,
              children: listImages,
              onPageChanged: (currentPage) {
                if (widget.onImageChange != null) {
                  widget.onImageChange!(_currentImageIndex, currentPage);
                }

                _currentImageIndex = currentPage;
              },
            );

            if (widget.onImageTap == null) {
              return pageView;
            }

            return GestureDetector(
              child: pageView,
              onTap: () => widget.onImageTap!(_currentImageIndex),
            );
          },
        ),
        widget.showIndicator
            ? Positioned(
                bottom: bottom,
                top: top,
                left: left,
                right: right,
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                      begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                      end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      colors: [
                        Colors.transparent,
                        Colors.black.withOpacity(0.8)
                      ],
                    ),
                    borderRadius: widget.borderRadius
                        ? (widget.noRadiusForIndicator
                            ? null
                            : BorderRadius.only(
                                bottomLeft:
                                    widget.radius ?? const Radius.circular(8.0),
                                bottomRight:
                                    widget.radius ?? const Radius.circular(8.0)))
                        : null,
                  ),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(widget.indicatorBgPadding),
                  child: Center(
                    child: DotsIndicator(
                      controller: _controller!,
                      itemCount: listImages.length,
                      color: widget.dotColor,
                      increasedColor: widget.dotIncreasedColor,
                      dotSize: widget.dotSize,
                      dotSpacing: widget.dotSpacing,
                      dotIncreaseSize: widget.dotIncreaseSize,
                      onPageSelected: (int page) {
                        _controller!.animateToPage(
                          page,
                          duration: widget.animationDuration,
                          curve: widget.animationCurve,
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            : Container(),
      ],
    );
  }
}

/// An indicator showing the currently selected page of a PageController
class DotsIndicator extends AnimatedWidget {
  const DotsIndicator(
      {Key? key,
      required this.controller,
      this.itemCount,
      this.onPageSelected,
      this.color,
      this.increasedColor,
      this.dotSize,
      this.dotIncreaseSize,
      this.dotSpacing})
      : super(key: key, listenable: controller);

  // The PageController that this DotsIndicator is representing.
  final PageController controller;

  // The number of items managed by the PageController
  final int? itemCount;

  // Called when a dot is tapped
  final ValueChanged<int>? onPageSelected;

  // The color of the dots.
  final Color? color;

  // The color of the increased dot.
  final Color? increasedColor;

  // The base size of the dots
  final double? dotSize;

  // The increase in the size of the selected dot
  final double? dotIncreaseSize;

  // The distance between the center of each dot
  final double? dotSpacing;

  Widget _buildDot(int index) {
    double selectedness = Curves.easeOut.transform(
      max(
        0.0,
        1.0 - ((controller.page ?? controller.initialPage) - index).abs(),
      ),
    );
    double zoom = 1.0 + (dotIncreaseSize! - 1.0) * selectedness;
    final dotColor = zoom > 1.0 ? increasedColor : color;

    return SizedBox(
      width: dotSpacing,
      child: Center(
        child: Material(
          color: dotColor,
          type: MaterialType.circle,
          child: SizedBox(
            width: dotSize! * zoom,
            height: dotSize! * zoom,
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () => onPageSelected!(index),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: List<Widget>.generate(itemCount!, _buildDot),
    );
  }
}

class WidgetCarousel extends StatefulWidget {
  //All the pages on this Carousel.
  final List pages;

  //The transition animation timing curve. Default is [Curves.ease]
  final Curve animationCurve;

  //The transition animation duration. Default is 300ms.
  final Duration animationDuration;

  // The base size of the dots. Default is 8.0
  final double dotSize;

  // The increase in the size of the selected dot. Default is 2.0
  final double dotIncreaseSize;

  // The distance between the center of each dot. Default is 25.0
  final double dotSpacing;

  // The Color of each dot. Default is Colors.white
  final Color dotColor;

  // The background Color of the dots. Default is [Colors.grey[800].withOpacity(0.5)]
  final Color? dotBgColor;

  // Enable or Disable the indicator (dots). Default is true
  final bool showIndicator;

  //Padding Size of the background Indicator. Default is 20.0
  final double indicatorBgPadding;

  //How to show the images in the box. Default is cover
  final BoxFit boxFit;

  //Enable/Disable radius Border for the images. Default is false
  final bool borderRadius;

  //Border Radius of the images. Default is [Radius.circular(8.0)]
  final Radius? radius;

  //Move the Indicator From the Bottom
  final double moveIndicatorFromBottom;

  //Remove the radius bottom from the indicator background. Default false
  final bool noRadiusForIndicator;

  //Enable/Disable Image Overlay Shadow. Default false
  final bool overlayShadow;

  //Choose the color of the overlay Shadow color. Default Colors.grey[800]
  final Color? overlayShadowColors;

  //Choose the size of the Overlay Shadow, from 0.0 to 1.0. Default 0.5
  final double overlayShadowSize;

  //Enable/Disable the auto play of the slider. Default true
  final bool autoplay;

  //Duration of the Auto play slider by seconds. Default 3 seconds
  final Duration autoplayDuration;

  const WidgetCarousel(
      {Key? key,
      required this.pages,
      this.animationCurve = Curves.ease,
      this.animationDuration = const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      this.dotSize = 8.0,
      this.dotSpacing = 25.0,
      this.dotIncreaseSize = 2.0,
      this.dotColor = Colors.white,
      this.dotBgColor,
      this.showIndicator = true,
      this.indicatorBgPadding = 20.0,
      this.boxFit = BoxFit.cover,
      this.borderRadius = false,
      this.radius,
      this.moveIndicatorFromBottom = 0.0,
      this.noRadiusForIndicator = false,
      this.overlayShadow = false,
      this.overlayShadowColors,
      this.overlayShadowSize = 0.5,
      this.autoplay = true,
      this.autoplayDuration = const Duration(seconds: 3)})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State createState() => WidgetCarouselState();
}

class WidgetCarouselState extends State<WidgetCarousel> {
  final _controller = PageController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    if (widget.autoplay) {
      Timer.periodic(widget.autoplayDuration, (_) {
        if (_controller.page == widget.pages.length - 1) {
          _controller.animateToPage(
            0,
            duration: widget.animationDuration,
            curve: widget.animationCurve,
          );
        } else {
          _controller.nextPage(
              duration: widget.animationDuration, curve: widget.animationCurve);
        }
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<Widget> listPages = widget.pages
        .map((widget) => Container(
              child: widget,
            ))
        .toList();

    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        PageView(
          physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          controller: _controller,
          children: listPages,
        ),
        widget.showIndicator
            ? Positioned(
                bottom: widget.moveIndicatorFromBottom,
                left: 0.0,
                right: 0.0,
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color:
                        widget.dotBgColor ?? Colors.grey[800]!.withOpacity(0.5),
                    borderRadius: widget.borderRadius
                        ? (widget.noRadiusForIndicator
                            ? null
                            : BorderRadius.only(
                                bottomLeft:
                                    widget.radius ?? const Radius.circular(8.0),
                                bottomRight:
                                    widget.radius ?? const Radius.circular(8.0)))
                        : null,
                  ),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(widget.indicatorBgPadding),
                  child: Center(
                    child: DotsIndicator(
                      controller: _controller,
                      itemCount: listPages.length,
                      color: widget.dotColor,
                      dotSize: widget.dotSize,
                      dotSpacing: widget.dotSpacing,
                      dotIncreaseSize: widget.dotIncreaseSize,
                      onPageSelected: (int page) {
                        _controller.animateToPage(
                          page,
                          duration: widget.animationDuration,
                          curve: widget.animationCurve,
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            : Container(),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

There's a file where i keep all my constants, which is referenced in this code. Here's the relevant bits.

```
const borderDouble = 8.0;
BorderRadius standardBorderRadius = BorderRadius.circular(borderDouble);
```

Enjoy